# iPhone: How to use Tesseract

Tags: iphone, ocr, tesseract

This is regarding use of Tesseract in an iPhone app. I followed the steps provided here:

http://iphone.olipion.com/cross-compilation/tesseract-ocr

Now I have 2 questions:

1) How to use this in my iPhone project (which files need to be included, methods need to be called, etc.)

2) I googled and found that I'll have to include libtesseract_api.a

but got this message:

`file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)`

Please help me to understand this.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have tried to run the app in Simulator, which will support i386 architecture.

Please follow [this link](http://robertcarlsen.net/2009/07/15/cross-compiling-for-iphone-dev-884) to make the static library.

Answer (score 0):

Start here:

http://tinsuke.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/how-to-cross-compiling-libraries-for-ios-armv6armv7i386/

and then follow this updated guide:

http://tinsuke.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-compile-and-use-tesseract-3-01-on-ios-sdk-5/

It will help you cross compile and build a universal library that contains the arm6/arm7/i386 all in the one statically linked library so it should work on simulator and device and be suitable for AppStore distribution.

Also if you have XCode 4.3 or higher beware and read the comments about how the developer directory has changed.