# Need some advices to learn OCR related techniques

Tags: ios, ocr, tesseract

I'm working on an OCR project for iPhone using tesseract OCR engine. I'm planning to write the following modules:

- Capture image from iPhone camera
- Pre-process on the image to refine it, in order to improve the OCR output.
- Divide the OCR output into meaningful fields.
- Define some rules for the OCR engine in order to neglect any undefined characters.
  (e.g. if the the OCR output is `0226s5242` I want it to ignore the `s` character)

I want to begin learning the topics related to these modules, I'm not aware of the OCR related techniques, so any advice will be very helpful, Thanks.

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow! What exactly is the question here? You seem to have a plan, which part of it are you stuck on? Are you just asking if this is a good way to attack this problem?

Comment: no, i want to study the topics related to these modules in order to achieve them, but i'm not aware of them right now.

Comment: This site is geared towards a Q&A format, where you ask a specific question and get an answer. What you're asking is very large in scope, and cannot be reasonably answered in this format. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then start with compiling tesseract for iphone.

[This link may help you.](http://iphone.olipion.com/cross-compilation/tesseract-ocr)

Also try below question:

[How to cross compile tesseract ocr engine for iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798626/how-to-cross-compile-tesseract-ocr-engine-for-iphone)

Then try some OCR demo : [Try it here](https://github.com/nolanbrown/Tesseract-iPhone-Demo)

And search in SOF, a lot of related links are here:

[implement tesseract OCR in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124197/implement-tesseract-ocr-in-iphone)

[iPhone: How to use Tesseract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969699/iphone-how-to-use-tesseract)

[Tesseract Example for Iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335524/tesseract-example-for-iphone)

etc are some of them..

Comment: thanks arkiaz, i already used tesseract with iPhone, now i'm searching to know the next step to take , what's the topics i need to study in order to achieve these modules?